# Clash of Clans crash on boot due to different icloud/gamecenter accounts?

Tags: technical-issues, clash-of-clans, ios, game-center

My sons both have Clash Of Clans on their IPod 4s'. Both IPods are linked to my Apple ID which I signed up with on a device that has been gone for a few years. It has been convenient for sharing purchases, etc., but I ended up making my older son his own Apple ID to log in with on GameCenter so that he can have his own COC. It has been working fine for a while but for the past few days his game has been crashing on boot. We have tried all of the usual steps including resetting, uninstalling/reinstalling, even making a backup, restoring to factory settings, restoring the backup, reinstalling the game and still it won't load. The other IPod which uses my ID for GameCenter and ICloud is still working fine.

I am not sure it's related but before this happened he got an ITunes card that we loaded onto my account with the intention of him spending it on treasure or whatever in the game. Ever since we loaded the money, even though he hasn't used any of it yet, this has been happening. I'm wondering if perhaps the problem is that his GameCenter account cannot access my Apple ID dollars. I was thinking the next step is resetting the device again "as a new IPod" and loading his Apple ID as the ICloud and the GameCenter both. This might work, but then I think he would lose access to previous purchases. Any insight appreciated. Sorry if this post is long winded and obtuse :)

Answer (score 1):

This question is really old but now supercell has created their own center 
Now just transferred game progress from Google play (Android) or Gamecenter (IOS) to supercell Id this will fix your error if still finding solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Backup first your iPad then do the factory reset, restore as "new device", then login again using your current apple id credentials.

I recently had an issue with my COC account, contacted COC support through the app contact us feature.  Did the factory reset thing and it worked for me.

What kind of crashing happens? is it the black screen exit after loading the game(after that COC intro sound)?

Comment: Hmm I will try this- it is crashing on the screen where the purple bar goes almost all the way across.

Answer (score 0):

New update seems to have fixed problem.  No issue with using money from my Itunes on his game center account either.